# Change charset and engine for Doctrine2's ManyToMany relationship's intermediary table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I'm building this ManyToMany relationship between my two entities in Symfony2 and wish to have the linking table to be of `charset` **latin1** and `engine` **MyISAM** (they are UTF-8 and InnoDB by default).

Here they are :

**Entity\Commande**

```
<?php
// ...
/**
 * Commande
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="commande", options={"collate"="latin1_general_ci", "charset"="latin1", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Commande
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Paiement", inversedBy="commandes", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="paiement_commande",
     * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="commande_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="paiement_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $paiements;
```

**Entity\Paiement**

```
<?php
// ...
/**
 * Paiement
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paiement", options={"collate"="latin1_general_ci", "charset"="latin1", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Paiement
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Commande", mappedBy="paiements", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="paiement_commande")
     */
    private $commandes;
```

As you can see, I know how to properly set this information for my entity tables but how can I do for the `paiement_commande` table?

---

I tried:

```
/*
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="paiement_commande", options={"collate"="latin1_general_ci", "charset"="latin1", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 */
private $commandes;
```

But I got, from the `$ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` command :

```
 [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                                                                                         
 [Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinTable declared on property Entity\Paiement::$commandes does not have a property named "options". Available properties: name, schema, joinColumns, inverseJoinColumns
```

How can I set this ManyToMany relationship between my two entities and still be able to specify both `engine` and `charset` for the newly created linking table?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot control the engine, character set, collation and other properties like this of join-tables through doctrine. As you can see, the `@JoinTable` annotation doesn't have an `options` argument, like `@Table` has.

But you can always manage these things manually and Doctrine won't complain (when validating the schema). So either create the join-table yourself, or have Doctrine create it and adjust it according to you wishes.

**Personal advise**

IMHO you shouldn't rely on Doctrine to create or alter your schema.

Using Doctrine's console commands to create and alter the database is fine for your development database, and also useful for getting an initial indication of what SQL you need (see `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql`).

But for production usage this SQL should *always* be manually revised. Doctrine simply doesn't always generate the correct SQL. Like the case you have, there are other edge-cases that it doesn't take into account.

**Other tools**

I suggest you take a look at some other tools to manage database migrations.

[Doctrine Migrations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/introduction.html) is one. Note that this tool relies on the Doctrine ORM to generate SQL (see `migrations:diff`), so you'll run into the same issues. The difference is that you can have it create "versions", which you can then revise and alter, until you have what you want. That final "version" is the thing you apply to your database.

Another popular migration tool is [Phinx](https://phinx.org/). It's more dynamic and framework independent (so it does not need Doctrine).

Comment: FYI: I sent a pull request to Doctrine2 that will hopefully fix this issue: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/5953

Answer (score 3):

A trick might be to use another entity as a join table.

Simply put :

```
<?php
// ...
/**
 * PaiementCommande
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="paiement_commande", options={"collate"="latin1_general_ci", "charset"="latin1", "engine":"MyISAM"})
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class PaiementCommande
{
    // ...

    /**         *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Commande")
     */
    private $commande;

    /**         *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Paiement")
     */
    private $paiement;
```

I think it is anyway better to use this kind of intermediate entity since at one point in your application you may need to store intermediate data, and this would be the only way to do this (and changing every piece of code related to the relation would be quite painful).

Answer (score 1):

My advise would be to let Doctrine and InnoDB do where they're good at, handling the referential integrity and relationships. Probably you want to use MyISAM for the search functionality, so would be better to create a copy of the relevant data for that.

You can hook into all events that Doctrine triggers, and make a copy of the entity data into another table. These events are really powerful and allow you to hook into almost every scenario: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html

You can create a subscriber in Symfony that focuses on handling all events for that entity: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine uses `foreign_keys` on any relation mapping - these are only available in `InnoDB`. 
In addition to that, doctrine will fail when you'll try to perform transaction on non-transactional engine (like MyISAM), [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#mysql-with-myisam-tables).
After all there are some [implementations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-972) in `Doctrine` 2.2 or 2.3